# Android app crashes on emulator - logCat shows no errors

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I have just added the SherlockActionBar library to my android project. After some small changes (FragmentActivity -> SherlockFragmentActivity, getActionBar() -> getSupportActionBar(), imports) it all compiled nicely. After I run the app, however, the debugger stops, as though it had encountered an exception. However, there are no errors shown in the LogCat output. I just can't wrap my head around what's going on.

Here is the logCat output after I terminate the app.

```
10-02 14:11:19.227: I/SystemUpdateService(174): UpdateTask at time 1349187079227
10-02 14:11:19.237: I/ActivityThread(328): Pub com.android.email.attachmentprovider: com.android.email.provider.AttachmentProvider
10-02 14:11:19.687: I/dalvikvm(81): Jit: resizing JitTable from 512 to 1024
10-02 14:11:19.809: D/MediaScannerService(150): start scanning volume internal: [/system/media]
10-02 14:11:20.047: V/AlarmClock(239): AlarmInitReceiver finished
10-02 14:11:20.087: I/ActivityManager(81): Start proc com.android.quicksearchbox for broadcast com.android.quicksearchbox/.SearchWidgetProvider: pid=346 uid=10012 gids={3003}
10-02 14:11:20.127: D/ExchangeService(320): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
10-02 14:11:20.427: I/ActivityThread(346): Pub com.android.quicksearchbox.google: com.android.quicksearchbox.google.GoogleSuggestionProvider
10-02 14:11:20.497: I/ActivityThread(346): Pub com.android.quicksearchbox.shortcuts: com.android.quicksearchbox.ShortcutsProvider
10-02 14:11:20.657: I/ActivityManager(81): Start proc com.android.music for broadcast com.android.music/.MediaAppWidgetProvider: pid=358 uid=10028 gids={3003, 1015}
10-02 14:11:20.927: D/ExchangeService(320): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onCreate
10-02 14:11:20.967: D/dalvikvm(260): GC_CONCURRENT freed 213K, 6% free 6409K/6791K, paused 5ms+101ms
10-02 14:11:21.077: D/ExchangeService(320): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = true, running = false
10-02 14:11:21.567: D/GTalkService(174): [ReonnectMgr] ### report Inet condition: status=false, networkType=0
10-02 14:11:21.587: D/ConnectivityService(81): reportNetworkCondition(0, 0)
10-02 14:11:21.597: D/ConnectivityService(81): Inet connectivity change, net=0, condition=0,mActiveDefaultNetwork=0
10-02 14:11:21.597: D/ConnectivityService(81): starting a change hold
10-02 14:11:21.697: D/GTalkService(174): [RawStanzaProvidersMgr] ##### searchProvidersFromIntent
10-02 14:11:21.697: D/GTalkService(174): [RawStanzaProvidersMgr] no intent receivers found
10-02 14:11:21.847: I/SystemUpdateService(174): cancelUpdate (empty URL)
10-02 14:11:21.847: E/TelephonyManager(174): Hidden constructor called more than once per process!
10-02 14:11:21.867: D/dalvikvm(174): GC_CONCURRENT freed 337K, 7% free 6561K/7047K, paused 5ms+4ms
10-02 14:11:21.917: D/GTalkService(174): [ReonnectMgr] ### report Inet condition: status=false, networkType=0
10-02 14:11:21.917: D/ConnectivityService(81): reportNetworkCondition(0, 0)
10-02 14:11:21.917: D/ConnectivityService(81): Inet connectivity change, net=0, condition=0,mActiveDefaultNetwork=0
10-02 14:11:21.917: D/ConnectivityService(81): currently in hold - not setting new end evt
10-02 14:11:21.990: E/TelephonyManager(174): Original: com.google.android.location, new: com.google.android.gsf
10-02 14:11:22.027: I/SystemUpdateService(174): removeAllDownloads (cancelUpdate)
10-02 14:11:22.127: D/dalvikvm(328): GC_CONCURRENT freed 205K, 6% free 6506K/6855K, paused 660ms+3ms
10-02 14:11:22.197: D/Eas Debug(320): Logging: 
10-02 14:11:22.319: D/dalvikvm(81): GREF has increased to 401
10-02 14:11:22.947: D/ExchangeService(320): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = true, running = false
10-02 14:11:23.130: D/Eas Debug(320): Logging: 
10-02 14:11:23.307: I//system/bin/fsck_msdos(29): Attempting to allocate 2044 KB for FAT
10-02 14:11:23.560: I/ActivityManager(81): Starting: Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.google.android.gsf/.update.SystemUpdateInstallDialog } from pid 174
10-02 14:11:23.587: I/ActivityManager(81): Starting: Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.google.android.gsf/.update.SystemUpdateDownloadDialog } from pid 174
10-02 14:11:24.087: W/ActivityManager(81): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{407c7320 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}
10-02 14:11:24.237: E/TelephonyManager(174): Hidden constructor called more than once per process!
10-02 14:11:24.237: E/TelephonyManager(174): Original: com.google.android.location, new: com.google.android.gsf
10-02 14:11:24.507: D/dalvikvm(174): GC_EXPLICIT freed 231K, 7% free 6596K/7047K, paused 4ms+6ms
10-02 14:11:24.607: D/ConnectivityService(81): Inet hold end, net=0, condition =0, published condition =0
10-02 14:11:24.607: D/ConnectivityService(81): no change in condition - aborting
10-02 14:11:24.707: D/dalvikvm(174): GC_EXPLICIT freed 17K, 7% free 6579K/7047K, paused 4ms+4ms
10-02 14:11:24.947: I//system/bin/fsck_msdos(29): ** Phase 2 - Check Cluster Chains
10-02 14:11:25.117: I//system/bin/fsck_msdos(29): ** Phase 3 - Checking Directories
10-02 14:11:25.128: I//system/bin/fsck_msdos(29): ** Phase 4 - Checking for Lost Files
10-02 14:11:25.167: I//system/bin/fsck_msdos(29): 12 files, 1044448 free (522224 clusters)
10-02 14:11:25.227: I/Vold(29): Filesystem check completed OK
10-02 14:11:25.227: I/Vold(29): Device /dev/block/vold/179:0, target /mnt/sdcard mounted @ /mnt/secure/staging
10-02 14:11:25.237: D/Vold(29): Volume sdcard state changing 3 (Checking) -> 4 (Mounted)
10-02 14:11:25.257: I/PackageManager(81): Updating external media status from unmounted to mounted
10-02 14:11:25.457: D/dalvikvm(303): GC_EXPLICIT freed 35K, 6% free 6242K/6595K, paused 3ms+312ms
10-02 14:11:25.987: D/ExchangeService(320): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = true, running = false
10-02 14:11:26.157: D/MediaScanner(150):  prescan time: 2905ms
10-02 14:11:26.167: D/MediaScanner(150):     scan time: 148ms
10-02 14:11:26.167: D/MediaScanner(150): postscan time: 2ms
10-02 14:11:26.167: D/MediaScanner(150):    total time: 3055ms
10-02 14:11:26.197: D/MediaScannerService(150): done scanning volume internal
10-02 14:11:26.237: D/MediaScannerService(150): start scanning volume external: [/mnt/sdcard]
10-02 14:11:26.497: D/dalvikvm(143): GC_EXPLICIT freed 234K, 8% free 7735K/8327K, paused 3ms+5ms
10-02 14:11:27.180: D/dalvikvm(143): GC_CONCURRENT freed 150K, 4% free 8004K/8327K, paused 7ms+3ms
10-02 14:11:27.397: D/dalvikvm(143): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 96K, 6% free 8310K/8775K, paused 76ms
10-02 14:11:27.580: D/dalvikvm(143): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 515K, 11% free 8135K/9095K, paused 79ms
10-02 14:11:27.829: D/dalvikvm(143): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3K, 5% free 8694K/9095K, paused 7ms+6ms
10-02 14:11:28.137: V/TLINE(143): new: android.text.TextLine@4065b280
10-02 14:11:28.527: D/dalvikvm(143): GC_CONCURRENT freed 729K, 10% free 8764K/9671K, paused 5ms+13ms
10-02 14:11:28.677: D/dalvikvm(143): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 152K, 11% free 8683K/9671K, paused 99ms
10-02 14:11:28.717: I/dalvikvm-heap(143): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.434MB for 2975968-byte allocation
10-02 14:11:28.807: D/dalvikvm(143): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 9% free 11589K/12615K, paused 84ms
10-02 14:11:29.159: D/dalvikvm(143): GC_CONCURRENT freed 197K, 7% free 12195K/12999K, paused 8ms+6ms
10-02 14:11:29.647: D/dalvikvm(143): GC_EXPLICIT freed 351K, 6% free 12790K/13511K, paused 8ms+17ms
10-02 14:11:29.717: I/SurfaceFlinger(32): Boot is finished (70768 ms)
10-02 14:11:29.877: I/ARMAssembler(32): generated scanline__00000177:03010104_00000002_00000000 [ 44 ipp] (66 ins) at [0x407c7290:0x407c7398] in 990662 ns
10-02 14:11:29.907: I/ARMAssembler(32): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00000001_00000000 [ 73 ipp] (95 ins) at [0x407c73a0:0x407c751c] in 989381 ns
10-02 14:11:30.287: D/dalvikvm(174): GC_EXPLICIT freed 25K, 8% free 6554K/7047K, paused 4ms+32ms
10-02 14:11:30.380: D/dalvikvm(143): GC_EXPLICIT freed 349K, 6% free 13124K/13895K, paused 5ms+25ms
10-02 14:11:30.957: D/dalvikvm(143): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1069K, 10% free 13860K/15239K, paused 81ms
10-02 14:11:32.177: D/dalvikvm(150): GC_CONCURRENT freed 183K, 6% free 6438K/6791K, paused 5ms+4ms
10-02 14:11:32.187: W/ActivityManager(81): No content provider found for: 
10-02 14:11:32.607: V/MediaScanner(150): pruneDeadThumbnailFiles... android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@406724a8
10-02 14:11:32.617: V/MediaScanner(150): /pruneDeadThumbnailFiles... android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@406724a8
10-02 14:11:32.640: W/ActivityManager(81): No content provider found for: 
10-02 14:11:32.640: D/VoldCmdListener(29): asec list
10-02 14:11:32.647: I/PackageManager(81): No secure containers on sdcard
10-02 14:11:32.667: D/MediaScanner(150):  prescan time: 107ms
10-02 14:11:32.667: D/MediaScanner(150):     scan time: 89ms
10-02 14:11:32.667: D/MediaScanner(150): postscan time: 61ms
10-02 14:11:32.667: D/MediaScanner(150):    total time: 257ms
10-02 14:11:32.697: W/PackageManager(81): Unknown permission android.permission.ADD_SYSTEM_SERVICE in package com.android.phone
10-02 14:11:32.707: W/PackageManager(81): Unknown permission com.android.smspush.WAPPUSH_MANAGER_BIND in package com.android.phone
10-02 14:11:32.737: W/PackageManager(81): Not granting permission android.permission.SEND_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED_INTENTS to package com.android.browser (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x9be45)
10-02 14:11:32.737: W/PackageManager(81): Not granting permission android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET to package com.android.widgetpreview (protectionLevel=3 flags=0x28be44)
10-02 14:11:32.767: W/PackageManager(81): Unknown permission android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA in package com.android.exchange
10-02 14:11:32.778: W/PackageManager(81): Unknown permission android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA in package com.android.email
10-02 14:11:32.788: W/PackageManager(81): Unknown permission com.android.providers.im.permission.READ_ONLY in package com.google.android.apps.maps
10-02 14:11:32.797: W/PackageManager(81): Not granting permission android.permission.DEVICE_POWER to package com.android.deskclock (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x8be45)
10-02 14:11:33.137: D/MediaScannerService(150): done scanning volume external
10-02 14:11:33.197: D/PackageParser(81): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl257911298.tmp
10-02 14:11:33.837: I/InputReader(81): Device reconfigured: id=0, name='qwerty2', surface size is now 1024x800
10-02 14:11:34.097: D/dalvikvm(81): GC_CONCURRENT freed 12185K, 47% free 13966K/26311K, paused 8ms+23ms
10-02 14:11:36.798: I/TabletStatusBar(124): DISABLE_CLOCK: no
10-02 14:11:36.798: I/TabletStatusBar(124): DISABLE_NAVIGATION: no
10-02 14:11:37.348: I/ARMAssembler(32): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001001_00000000 [ 91 ipp] (114 ins) at [0x407c7520:0x407c76e8] in 919320 ns
10-02 14:11:37.598: I/TabletStatusBar(124): DISABLE_BACK: no
10-02 14:11:37.710: I/ActivityManager(81): Displayed com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher: +46s212ms
10-02 14:11:38.817: D/dalvikvm(143): GC_CONCURRENT freed 969K, 8% free 14867K/16007K, paused 4ms+10ms
10-02 14:11:39.437: I/dalvikvm(81): Jit: resizing JitTable from 1024 to 2048
10-02 14:11:40.267: D/dalvikvm(143): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2357K, 16% free 14395K/17031K, paused 80ms
10-02 14:11:40.717: D/dalvikvm(143): GC_EXPLICIT freed 742K, 16% free 14358K/17031K, paused 8ms+4ms
10-02 14:11:41.617: D/dalvikvm(81): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1955K, 48% free 13869K/26311K, paused 9ms+10ms
10-02 14:11:42.559: D/dalvikvm(81): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1830K, 48% free 13881K/26311K, paused 9ms+9ms
10-02 14:11:42.758: I/PackageManager(81): Removing non-system package:cz.trilimi.sfaui
10-02 14:11:42.758: I/ActivityManager(81): Force stopping package cz.trilimi.sfaui uid=10036
10-02 14:11:42.967: D/PackageManager(81): Scanning package cz.trilimi.sfaui
10-02 14:11:42.967: I/PackageManager(81): Package cz.trilimi.sfaui codePath changed from /data/app/cz.trilimi.sfaui-1.apk to /data/app/cz.trilimi.sfaui-2.apk; Retaining data and using new
10-02 14:11:42.967: I/PackageManager(81): Unpacking native libraries for /data/app/cz.trilimi.sfaui-2.apk
10-02 14:11:43.097: D/installd(35): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/cz.trilimi.sfaui-2.apk' ---
10-02 14:11:45.317: D/dalvikvm(391): DexOpt: load 434ms, verify+opt 1260ms
10-02 14:11:45.407: D/installd(35): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/cz.trilimi.sfaui-2.apk' (success) ---
10-02 14:11:45.407: W/PackageManager(81): Code path for pkg : cz.trilimi.sfaui changing from /data/app/cz.trilimi.sfaui-1.apk to /data/app/cz.trilimi.sfaui-2.apk
10-02 14:11:45.407: W/PackageManager(81): Resource path for pkg : cz.trilimi.sfaui changing from /data/app/cz.trilimi.sfaui-1.apk to /data/app/cz.trilimi.sfaui-2.apk
10-02 14:11:45.407: D/PackageManager(81):   Activities: cz.trilimi.sfaui.ItemListActivity cz.trilimi.sfaui.ItemDetailActivity
10-02 14:11:45.427: I/ActivityManager(81): Force stopping package cz.trilimi.sfaui uid=10036
10-02 14:11:45.657: I/installd(35): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@cz.trilimi.sfaui-2.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@cz.trilimi.sfaui-2.apk@classes.dex
10-02 14:11:45.657: D/PackageManager(81): New package installed in /data/app/cz.trilimi.sfaui-2.apk
10-02 14:11:45.997: I/ActivityManager(81): Force stopping package cz.trilimi.sfaui uid=10036
10-02 14:11:46.147: D/dalvikvm(143): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3K, 16% free 14356K/17031K, paused 10ms+9ms
10-02 14:11:46.237: D/PackageManager(81): generateServicesMap(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator): 3 services unchanged
10-02 14:11:46.277: D/PackageManager(81): generateServicesMap(android.content.SyncAdapter): 5 services unchanged
10-02 14:11:46.337: D/PackageManager(81): generateServicesMap(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator): 3 services unchanged
10-02 14:11:46.347: D/PackageManager(81): generateServicesMap(android.content.SyncAdapter): 5 services unchanged
10-02 14:11:46.437: D/dalvikvm(208): GC_EXPLICIT freed 258K, 7% free 6488K/6919K, paused 3ms+5ms
10-02 14:11:46.477: W/RecognitionManagerService(81): no available voice recognition services found
10-02 14:11:46.897: I/ActivityManager(81): Start proc com.svox.pico for broadcast com.svox.pico/.VoiceDataInstallerReceiver: pid=398 uid=10006 gids={}
10-02 14:11:47.087: I/ActivityThread(398): Pub com.svox.pico.providers.SettingsProvider: com.svox.pico.providers.SettingsProvider
10-02 14:11:47.138: D/GTalkService(174): [GTalkService.1] handlePackageInstalled: re-initialize providers
10-02 14:11:47.147: D/GTalkService(174): [RawStanzaProvidersMgr] ##### searchProvidersFromIntent
10-02 14:11:47.147: D/GTalkService(174): [RawStanzaProvidersMgr] no intent receivers found
10-02 14:11:47.718: I/AccountTypeManager(208): Loaded meta-data for 1 account types, 0 accounts in 186ms
10-02 14:11:48.377: D/dalvikvm(143): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1865K, 15% free 14513K/17031K, paused 7ms+4ms
10-02 14:11:48.917: D/dalvikvm(208): GC_CONCURRENT freed 219K, 6% free 6788K/7175K, paused 7ms+73ms
10-02 14:11:49.207: D/dalvikvm(143): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4558K, 31% free 11866K/17031K, paused 89ms
10-02 14:11:49.587: D/dalvikvm(143): GC_CONCURRENT freed 713K, 24% free 13010K/17031K, paused 5ms+4ms
10-02 14:11:49.967: D/dalvikvm(143): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1046K, 19% free 13922K/17031K, paused 5ms+4ms
10-02 14:11:50.437: D/dalvikvm(81): GC_EXPLICIT freed 898K, 47% free 13955K/26311K, paused 6ms+39ms
10-02 14:11:50.467: I/installd(35): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@cz.trilimi.sfaui-1.apk@classes.dex
10-02 14:11:50.477: D/AndroidRuntime(227): Shutting down VM
10-02 14:11:50.507: D/dalvikvm(227): GC_CONCURRENT freed 97K, 84% free 331K/2048K, paused 1ms+2ms
10-02 14:11:50.507: I/AndroidRuntime(227): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
10-02 14:11:50.517: D/jdwp(227): adbd disconnected
10-02 14:11:51.177: D/AndroidRuntime(410): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
10-02 14:11:51.177: D/AndroidRuntime(410): CheckJNI is ON
10-02 14:11:51.897: D/AndroidRuntime(410): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
10-02 14:11:51.937: I/ActivityManager(81): Force stopping package cz.trilimi.sfaui uid=10036
10-02 14:11:51.937: I/ActivityManager(81): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=cz.trilimi.sfaui/.ItemListActivity } from pid 410
10-02 14:11:51.968: W/WindowManager(81): Failure taking screenshot for (230x179) to layer 21005
10-02 14:11:51.997: I/ActivityManager(81): Start proc cz.trilimi.sfaui for activity cz.trilimi.sfaui/.ItemListActivity: pid=418 uid=10036 gids={}
10-02 14:11:52.007: D/AndroidRuntime(410): Shutting down VM
10-02 14:11:52.057: I/AndroidRuntime(410): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
10-02 14:11:52.097: D/dalvikvm(410): GC_CONCURRENT freed 98K, 83% free 360K/2048K, paused 1ms+0ms
10-02 14:11:52.097: D/jdwp(410): adbd disconnected
10-02 14:11:53.147: W/ActivityThread(418): Application cz.trilimi.sfaui is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
10-02 14:11:53.207: I/System.out(418): Sending WAIT chunk
10-02 14:11:53.217: I/dalvikvm(418): Debugger is active
10-02 14:11:53.447: I/System.out(418): Debugger has connected
10-02 14:11:53.457: I/System.out(418): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-02 14:11:53.637: I/ARMAssembler(32): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001002_00000000 [ 87 ipp] (110 ins) at [0x407c76f0:0x407c78a8] in 598498 ns
10-02 14:11:53.660: I/System.out(418): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-02 14:11:53.857: I/System.out(418): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-02 14:11:54.057: I/System.out(418): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-02 14:11:54.257: I/System.out(418): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-02 14:11:54.317: V/TLINE(81): new: android.text.TextLine@4155dde8
10-02 14:11:54.467: I/System.out(418): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-02 14:11:54.667: I/System.out(418): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-02 14:11:54.870: I/System.out(418): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-02 14:11:55.027: D/dalvikvm(143): GC_EXPLICIT freed 900K, 16% free 14420K/17031K, paused 7ms+4ms
10-02 14:11:55.067: I/System.out(418): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-02 14:11:55.292: I/System.out(418): debugger has settled (1315)
10-02 14:12:02.008: W/ActivityManager(81): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
10-02 14:12:02.971: W/ActivityManager(81): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{4078c6b0 cz.trilimi.sfaui/.ItemListActivity}
10-02 14:12:08.359: D/ExchangeService(320): Received deviceId from Email app: androidc259148960
10-02 14:12:08.507: D/ExchangeService(320): Reconciling accounts...
10-02 14:16:11.437: D/SntpClient(81): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
10-02 14:17:21.573: W/jdwp(418): Debugger is telling the VM to exit with code=1
10-02 14:17:21.573: I/dalvikvm(418): GC lifetime allocation: 8642 bytes
10-02 14:17:21.637: D/Zygote(33): Process 418 exited cleanly (1)
10-02 14:17:21.651: I/ActivityManager(81): Process cz.trilimi.sfaui (pid 418) has died.
10-02 14:17:21.847: D/dalvikvm(143): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 16% free 14420K/17031K, paused 7ms+7ms
10-02 14:17:21.917: W/InputManagerService(81): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40bfbf28
```

Comment: Check if you are requesting Window features in any of your activities (such as NO_TITLE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I managed to fix it, I don't precisely know what fixed it. Either restarting Eclipse and emulator and LogCat or resetting the debug configuration or maybe even something else.

LogCat then showed an error: missing the Sherlock.theme

So that might have been the actual cause of the crashes (but it also might have not).